# How to make a scoped variable global in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, global-variables, scoped

I am working on a large project and require to make a scoped variable global so it can be accessed throughout the whole class.

A simple scenario of where this might be used is to make the integer `x` global.

```
class a
{
public:
    a()
    {
        int x;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

A more complex scenario may include making `FunctionTypeClass<FunctionType> FunctionTypeDataStore`:

```
class thread
{
public:
    template<typename FunctionType>
    thread(FunctionType* function)
    {
        FunctionTypeClass<FunctionType> FunctionTypeDataStore;
    }

    FunctionTypeClass get_function_type()
    {
        return FunctionTypeDataStore;
    }


    ~thread()
    {
    }

    template<typename StoreFunctionTypeTemp>
    class FunctionTypeClass
    {
        StoreFunctionTypeTemp Variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should find out what a member variable is, before starting making variables global

Comment: "so it can be accessed throughout the whole class." thats a member variable, you don't need a global for that

Comment: Can't you make it a data member of the class itself?? `class a{ intx; }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a member variable out of it and your class templated, not the constructor:

```
template<typename FunctionType>
class thread
{
private:
    template<typename StoreFunctionTypeTemp>
    class FunctionTypeClass
    {
        StoreFunctionTypeTemp Variable;
    };

    FunctionTypeClass<FunctionType> FunctionTypeDataStore;
public:

    thread(FunctionType* function) { }

    FunctionTypeClass<FunctionType> get_function_type()
    {
        return FunctionTypeDataStore;
    }
};
```

Comment: Although this does work, I was hoping to get a solution which involves making a scoped variable global. For example, their is a `global` keyword in python which can make a scoped variable global.

Comment: @anom1 please understand that Python is Not c++ and you should be using the standards provided by the language Not trying to mimick Bad behavior from other languages